# Is it possible to change the url of WebPage on Page_Load in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo

I am working on a project. Here we are dynamically generating web pages. The web page code renders on Page_Load() and it is generating data based on query string.

I implemented it like

```
http://www.example.com/Request.aspx?cPanelId=(here query string)
```

The problem is that **Seo** will not work on Query string.

If I could change could change the url in this way like

```
http://www.example.com/(Requested query string Page.aspx)
```

It will work fine.

Is it implementable?

Comment: this is called: url rewriting... a module from IIS which rewrite your url ... don't try  this in page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is implementable in ASP.NET and the name of the concept is URL rewriting. please have a  look at the following url(s) for detailed understanding and how to implement it in your project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: helpful bro! I used webconfig method